# node-rdkafka publish message using REST apis

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Trying to explore the options to publish a message from nodeJs client to Apache Kafka, is there any option to publish message using REST api?

I am using [node-rdkafka](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rdkafka) library to connect to kafka from nodeJs application.

Comment: And what's the issue using that rdkafka library?

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to achieve here. 
Do you want the message you have sent to Kafka to be forwarded to a REST service?
Or would you prefer not to have to use the node-rdkafka library and instead use REST to send your message to Kafka?

In any case both of these scenarios can be achieved by using the Confluent REST Proxy for Apache Kafka. You can find the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest) or download a compiled version as part of [Confluent Open Source](https://www.confluent.io/product/confluent-open-source/)